# Unity Scene-to-Scene inter-object communication: HOW?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, communication

Unity has an ability to have one scene act as a host for other sub-scenes, additively and asynchronously loaded, later in the game.

What are the ways an object in a host scene can know of and be sure of communicating with an object in an additively loaded sub-scene?

And the inverse, how can an object in the additively loaded scene communicate with an object in its host scene?

Answer (score 1):

First, in Unity's UnityEngine.SceneManagement package, you can use `SceneManager.GetSceneByName("scene name here")` which returns `Scene`. If the scene is null, then the scene is not yet loaded. If it is, you can use `isLoaded` to check if it is loaded, [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html). You can either use `Find` after that, but I do not recommend this as it is a slow process.

Second, if the object you are referring to is a `GameObject` and you need a component attached to it, you can use [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) pattern so you can access the only instance of the script. You can just assign `instance = null` under `OnDestroy` so that the instance will be gone when the scene is unloaded. This option is viable if the script is in the host scene since, I assume, it is not unloaded/destroyed.